# use a CALayer as a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, calayer, bezier

I would like to create a `CALayer` bezier path in a circle shape.  And I would like to set it like it was a `UIImageView` (to be able to move it with animation etc.) Is it possible? If so how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you essentially want to mask a UIImageView with a circle?

Comment: no just create a circle without uiimageview :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "`CALayer` bezier path" but you have a couple of options here:

1. Create a subclass of UIView, where you draw your circle using `UIBezierPath` methods in the `drawRect:`. This view can then be added to another view as a subview and animated using standard methods. However, you are warned that this may affect performance, (as it has to keep re-drawing) so if that does turn out to be a problem...
2. Create a graphics context and draw your circle in there. Take an image from this graphics context and set it as the image for a `UIImageView`. Animate as in answer (1). This way you aren't redrawing all the time so performance would be better, but try with option 1 first as it is simpler, and if you have simple drawing code it shouldn't affect you too much.

For option 2, you begin a graphics context using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` - you then do your drawing, and extract the image using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, then end the context using `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`. Those functions are all documented [here](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Sample code to do this:

```
CGFloat radius = 50;
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(radius*2,radius*2);
CGPoint centre = CGPointMake(radius,radius);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO, 0.0);
UIBezierPath * solidPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centre radius:edgeSize/20 startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
[solidPath closePath];
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[solidPath fill];

UIImage *circle = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:circle];
```

Comment: how can I do it is there a code or a link to do this please ??

Comment: see updated answer, I can't give you a full sample at the moment, is this enough for you?

Comment: not really but I can wait. take your time and i will wait for full answer because now I won't be able to do it :/

Comment: You also have to add the image view as a subview to something that is also on the screen. I thought you already had that part.

Comment: it works but it would be great if you look at this link:[link](http://tumbljack.com/post/179975074/complex-interpolation-with-cashapelayer-free)  and the sample code there.In this code the author modify the shape of a layer .And I would like to know how to put the layer of the code in a uiimageView like you did here ?

Comment: That is a different question.

Comment: that's is right so I will ask it as a question and I'm waiting for you :)

Comment: here is the question :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325492/assign-a-calayer-to-a-uiimageview-to-be-able-to-do-all-you-can-do-with-a-uiimage)

Answer (score 2):

You could always add a CAShapeLayer to your view.  During init, do something like (all untested):

```
CAShapeLayer *circle = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[self.layer addSublayer:circle];
```

Then, in drawRect, layoutSubViews, or some other place that seems appropriate to update the layout:

```
circle.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
CGMutablePathRef p = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(p, NULL, self.bounds);
circle.path = p;
circle.bounds = self.bounds;
circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution. But don't forget your `.CGColor` on the fillColor.