# assign a CAlayer to a UIImageView to be able to do all you can do with a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview, calayer

Hi every one there is a link :[link](http://tumbljack.com/post/179966754) and there is a sample code in it  where the author use a CALayer with CAShapeLayer.What I would like is to use this CALayer like it was a uiimageView (maybe assign to a uiimageview) to be able to move it etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the layer type of an existing `UIView` (meaning: you also can't change the layer of an `UIImageView`), but drawing to a layer is pretty easy: you need to assign a delegate to your `CALayer`, and that delegate needs to implement [drawLayer:inContext:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/drawLayer%3ainContext%3a).

Another solution might be to create a `UIView` subclass and implement `+layerClass`:

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}
```

That way your view will use a shape layer and you might be able to simply use the usual `UIView`'s `drawRect:` method. You could then access the layer via `(CAShapeLayer *)[self layer]` to modify it. I haven't tried this approach, though.

**Edit:** Explaining how the second solution would be done:

```
@interface MyView : UIView {
    UIImage *image;
}
@property(retain) UIImage *image;
@end


@implementation MyView
@synthesize image;

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.image = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Draw the image. You might need to play around with this,
    // for example to draw the image as aspect fit or aspect fill.
    [image drawInRect:rect];
}
@end
```

Comment: I don't really understand the second solution.What I really want is that I can use CALayer for moving it like :imageView.center=CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y); and instead of imageView put my layer :)

Comment: I don't really understand the : + (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}

Comment: It tells your `UIView` to use a `CAShapeLayer` as backing store. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/layerClass).

Comment: in the sample code the name of the CALayer is 'rootLayer' so I have to put instead of 'layerClass' 'rootLayer' ?

Comment: No. If you're going for a pure layer based solution, then you need to give your `CAShapeLayer` a delegate in implement `drawLayer:inContext:` in that delegate. Search for examples on how to do drawing with layers. The second solution I presented to you is  to use a `UIView` instead. Every `UIView` has one backing layer, which you access its layer through the `layer` property. You can tell `UIView` what kind of layer to use for the backing layer with `layerClass`.

Comment: There various kinds of `CALayer`, like `CAShapeLayer` or `CATiledLayer`. Usually a UIView simply uses the normal `CALayer`. Please read up on UIViews and their relation with layers and maybe also a [CALayer tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/introduction-to-calayers-tutorial).

Comment: yes I understand all of these but, my problem is the following : where do I create the layer on another page.m ?and what is the class in your code ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand you. I have no idea what you mean with `page.m`. You either create a layer directly, like `[[CAShapedLayer alloc] init]` or if you want it managed by an UIView, you implement the `+layerClass` method. And I don't know which of the classes in my code you're meaning.